# Multiple if statements in an html attribute - MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

If I wanted multiple if statements in an html attribute I might do something like this:

```
  <input type="button" value="Bad, the title has a lot of excess spacing" title="@if(SomeModel.condOne) {
                              <text>this</text>
                              }
                              @if (SomeModel.CondTwo)
                              {
                              <text> is</text>
                              }
                              @if (SomeModel.CondThree)
                              {
                              <text> a title</text>
                              }      
                             " />
```

But that creates a lot of empty spaces that need truncating.  So this works:

```
  <input type="button" value="Good, the title is condenced" title="@if(SomeModel.condOne) {<text>this</text>}@if (SomeModel.CondTwo){<text> is</text>}@if (SomeModel.CondThree){<text> a title</text>}" />
```

The same principle can be applied to an element with multiple classes (e.g. class="oddrow class1" -> class="evenrow class2")

But that might be hard to read if it's a long line.  And visual studio has a habit of breaking that statement into multiple lines if you touch the bracket or Ctrl-K,Ctrl-D (which any next developer is likely to do).

Is there a better or more fullproof way to implement multiple attribute conditions in a line for MVC razor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating a small helpers method that returns the text you need.

You'd have to pass it `SomeModel` and inside that method check for your condition that way you'd have something nicer to look at and easier to maintain.

For example:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static string FetchTitle(this HtmlHelper helper, SomeModel model)
    {
        //Your logic here.
    }
}
```

You can read all about Html Helper methods here on [Jon Galloway's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/23/comparing-mvc-3-helpers-using-extension-methods-and-declarative-razor-helper.aspx).

That's where I learned how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it as:

```
title="@if(SomeModel.condOne) { <text>this</text> }
       @if (SomeModel.CondTwo) { <text> is</text> }
       @if (SomeModel.CondThree) { <text> a title</text> }      
                             " />
```

Helper makes sense if you do use this same logic alot, especially assuming the same model, but you may want to also consider a helper that uses a `Func<>` expression or `Action<>` expression.  This way, it wouldn't be tied to one model.